# Linux - is there a way to get the file size of a directory BUT only including the files that have a last modified / creation date of x?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesize

as per title I am trying to find a way to get the file size of a directory (using du) but only counting the files in the directory that have been created (or modified) after a specific date.

Is it something that can be done using the command line?

Thanks :)

Comment: Assuming that you have GNU `find` you could use `find` with condition `-mtime` to check for the modification time and action `-printf` to print the file size, and pipe the result to a program that can add the values, e.g. an `awk` script. (Detailed implementation left as an exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 2):

From @Bodo's comment. Using GNU find:

```sh
find directory/ -type f -newermt 2021-11-25 -printf "%s\t %f\n" | \
awk '{s += $1 } END { print s }' | \
numfmt --to=iec-i
```

1. [find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html) looks in in `directory/` (*change this*)
2. Looks for files (`-type f`)
3. that have a [newer modified time](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Comparing-Timestamps.html) than 2021-11-25 (`-newermt`) (*change this*)
4. and outputs the files's size (`%s`) on each line
5. adds up all the sizes from the lines with [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) `{s += $1 }`
6. Prints the results `END { print s }`
7. Formats the byte value to human readable with [numfmt](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/numfmt-invocation.html)'s `--to=iec-i`